# Specification for Eye Mask Creation?

Tags: lvds, eye-diagram

I want to create an eye mask which I can apply at the Rx eye diagram up to which I can quantify the quality of my signal at the Rx. Now my question is what are the specifications to determine eye mask which is standard? I am creating SERDES channel with different channel parameters. Now at the Rx by looking at the ripples of the voltages, I can say which is good or bad. But that is not enough for the documentation of my thesis conclusion. I have to quantify with a quality. I can create an eye mask with a defined parameter, which I can say keep out of zone area. Now I am not asking now how to make the file. I am asking based on what I will specify an standard eye which I can apply and say that if it crosses this eye mask the signal integrity is not good at the Rx. Can anyone help me? I know the mask region is defined as follows:

> - Top region: The maximum expected value. Voltages exceeding this value will fail.
> - Middle Region: The size and shape of the eye diagram as defined by the interface standard for the high speed digital signal.
> - Bottom Region: The minimum expected value. Voltages below this value will fail

Now I am confused how to specify those regions — based on what?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very crude plan, but it should get you started.

Your typical mask will look like this:

[image]

Now we have to figure out how to define each of the three regions shown in red. For that, we need to get the SERDES datasheet and look up the numbers.

The bar on the top, as you already know, indicates the maximum allowed voltage. It means that, if the input signal exceeds this voltage, the chip could malfunction or get damaged. That voltage could be found in the datasheet section called "Absolute Maximum Ratings" or something like this.

The bar on the bottom could be defined similarly.

For the middle region, you can use a timing diagram and pretty much copy the elongated hexagon in the middle.

The top level of the hexagon should correspond to the minimum level for input voltage for logical 1, VIH in the datasheet.

The bottom level should correspond to the maximum level of the input voltage for logical 0, VIL.

The slopes of the edges should not exceed the maximum values specified for tLH and tHL.

The width of the hexagon should not be less than the sum of the minimum setup and hold times, tsu and thold, assuming that the sampling clock edge will be optimally placed somewhere in the middle.

Again, this is a very crude and simplistic approach, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: thanks for your simple explanation. I got your idea.  I am using Cadence Virtuoso version IC6.1.5.500.6. I cannot find to create mask after creating eye diagram from netlist. Will I have to define that in a text editor just like that? as I know mask file extension is ".msk". Now in the eye diagram tool how to define it. I know in the lastest Virtuoso version there is option load industry standard eye diagram. But how to do it in the prior versions?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar with this tool. May be you should post this as a separate question or google it.