Display port eye diagram evaluation
I was testing my display port diagram, all 4 lines.
The first three look good, the 4th line looks like it has only one signal (not differential.)
My question:

Is the 4th line okey to be like this. (Maybe this is clock or something else?)
Are the other ones okay? I don't really know how to evaluate diagrams.

FIRST LINE:

SECOND LINE:

THIRD LINE:

FOURTH LINE:


Is this LVDS? Can you overlay, or draw, the limit lines from the spec?

See more here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365685/specification-for-eye-mask-creation

This is displayport lines. And the big question is Line 4, if It's okey or not

Apply the eye mask and check. https://download.tek.com/document/61W_17974_6_HR_Letter_0.pdf

"And the big question is Line 4, if It's okey or not" ... do you get an image on the display? Please expand on why you're looking at the signals (curious, debugging an issue, development, etc...) What probe are you using? (differential?)

Lane 4 does indeed look like a clock - it's a repeating signal, and therefore at that distance from the trigger point, you still see the same signal... for the first three lanes, the signal level changes to indicate the data - thus you see an eye diagram for the two states the signal can have at the sample point.

@Attie Not low, your calculations are way off. HDMI clock is the pixel rate and the clock is around 148 MHz - likely 1080p at about 4.5 Gbps.

@Justme Oh, you're right... I was looking at the freq on the cursors not the signal, and missed the different horizontal scale for clock vs data eyes (duh...) I also didn't realise it was a pixel clock, not bit clock - thanks for sharing.

Yes, I get an image but I want to evaluate my design...I got SOM75 and then few PCBs, and then DisplayPort connector which goes to the Monitor.

This is likely not DP protocol on DP lines but HDMI protocol which has 3 data lanes and a clock lane. DP has no clock lane, but it can use variable amount of lanes depending on the need, but IIRC, three lanes is not possible, only 1, 2 and 4 are.
If the output supports DP++ then it may be that the port has switched to HDMI mode for some hardware or software bug.

Hello, It is DP (goes from SOM7583 via few PCBs to the DP connector. After that goes via DP/HDMI cables to the Monitor with HDMI input)

@DomenIvanc Then it's not DP but HDMI if you have a passive/DP++ adapter
